# Include remote JQuery-UI.css, problem in FF

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, firefox

I include remote `JQuery` and `JQuery-UI` from Google. The page works for Chrome and Opera, but in FF it seems the JQuery UI styles are not loaded. In Firebug, when I open the page code and check the `css` file for the `JQuery-UI`, instead of the content I see:

`Reload the page to get source for: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css`

My header file is:

```
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<link type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.js">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.15/jquery-ui.js">
<link type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu" rel="stylesheet">
<link type="text/css" href="css/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
```

EDIT:

I checked with the newest versions of the libraries, and still nothing

Comment: Have you tried it without Firebug running. Sometimes my Firebug seems to not like grabbing stuff via HTTPs? Or perhaps getting them not through HTTPS (change the Script SRC to http://theurl rather than https://theurl)

Comment: @Rob Quincey: thanks for hint, actually I changed from http to https in jquery-ui.css reference, and it runs : ) Strange, though

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the script tags. It should work then.